Weird CSS animation when trying to stagger animation object flying in from outside of overflow hidden
I'm trying to animate objects flying in from outside of an overflow hidden div, then one by one the objects would shrink to disappear and a different object will appear to replace the original one.
The problem I'm facing is there is a weird animation happening, where it's animating from final position (B), to the start position (A) and then back to final position (B), weird thing is this only applies to some of the objects, so I am very confused, hope someone can point the mistakes out. Some of them especially the ones that has longer timeout might not be very obvious but if you look closely they are flying very quickly in the background out of the overflow hidden div and then flew back with normal speed to final position
Some of the testing that I was experimenting was when all the timeout are all changed to 100ms, everything will become smooth, but once I tried to set the timeout further apart from each other, the ones with longer timeout will tend to fly from position A to position B then back to position A. I tried to edit the example on codepen.io  to make the animation more obvious by changing the timeout 1 second apart from each other.

But I wanted is just from A to B

I used animation with forwards, tried to make the start position more dynamically further away by using vw instead of px, added animation to the parent, none of them really works. I think there is something going on with the setTimeout there.
            .section-3-expand-parent-1 {
                animation: flyIn 2.5s forwards;
            }

Here is the codepen to the attempt that I made
https://codepen.io/Henry-Choo/pen/pomPBeV

I edited the post, some of the attempts I made is to extend the settimeout delay but the longer the delay the more obvious the unwanted animation becomes, I tried using animation delay as well, but that doesnt work, I tried to make the items start position way further away by like a few thousand px away or few hundred vw away from the overflow hidden div but that didn't work as well

Anyways, I fixed it lol, I just added the classname that has the final position when the timeout starts, so it wont immediately trigger the animation before the timeout us starting
<div id="parent8" class="section-3-expand-parent pin-8-variables"></div>

setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("label_8").classList.add("show");
      document.getElementById("pin_8").classList.add("pin-animation");
      document
       .getElementById("parent8")
       .classList.add("section-3-expand-parent-8");
     }, 4500);


